# Return max value from a SQL selection

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I do have a table license_Usage where which works like a log of the usage of licenses in a day

```
ID   User        license    date
1    1            A      22/2/2015
2    1            A      23/2/2015
3    1            B      22/2/2015
4    2            A      22/2/2015
```

Where I want to Count how many licenses per user in a day, the result shoul look like:

```
QuantityOfLicenses         User      date
        2                   1      22/2/2015
        1                   2      22/2/2015
```

For that I did the following query :

```
select count(license) as [Quantity of licenses],[user],[date]
From license_Usage
where date = '22/2/2015'
Group by [date], [user]
```

which works, but know I want to know which user have used the most number of licenses, for that I did the following query:

```
select MAX(result.[Quantity of licenses])
From (
     select count(license) as [Quantity of licenses],[user],[date]
     From license_Usage
     Group by [date], [user]
    ) as result
```

And it returns the max value of 2, but when I want to know which user have used 2 licenses,I try this query with no success :

```
select result.user, MAX(result.[Quantity of licenses])
From (
     select count(license) as [Quantity of licenses],[user],[date]
     From license_Usage
     Group by [date], [user]
    ) as result
Group by result.user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
select top 1 *
From (
     select count(license) as Quantity,[user],[date]
     From license_Usage
     Group by [date], [user]
    ) as result
order by Quantity desc
```

If you need to have a fetch that fetches all the rows that have max in case there's several, then you'll have to use rank() window function

Comment: This works, but I wish to know why the follow produces a diferent value

select result, MAX(result.Quantity of licenses)
From (
     select count(license) as Quantitiy of licenses,user,date
     From license_Usage
     Group by date, user
    ) as result
Group by result.user

Comment: If you have group by user, you will get one row per user -- that's the purpose of group by, telling on what level you want the results be grouped to.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RANK` to rank the users by the number of licenses per day.

```
SELECT
  LicPerDay.*,
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [date] ORDER BY Qty DESC) AS User_Rank
FROM (
  SELECT
    COUNT(license) AS Qty,
    User,
    [date]
  FROM license_usage
  GROUP BY User, [date]
) LicPerDay
```

Any user with `User_Rank` = 1 will have the most licenses for that day.

If you only want the top user for each day, wrap the query above as a subquery and filter on `User_Rank = 1`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    LicPerDay.*,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [date] ORDER BY Qty) AS User_Rank
  FROM (
    SELECT
      COUNT(license) AS Qty,
      User,
      [date]
    FROM license_usage
    GROUP BY User, [date]
  ) LicPerDay
) LicPerDayRanks
WHERE User_Rank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Windowed Aggregate Function, RANK, to get the highest count:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
      User,
      [date]
      COUNT(license) AS Qty,
      -- rank by descending number for each day ??
      --RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [date] ORDER BY COUNT(license) DESC) AS rnk
      -- rank by descending number
      RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(license) DESC) AS rnk
    FROM license_usage
    GROUP BY User, [date]
  ) dt
WHERE rnk = 1
```